# Как развернуть свернутый браузер ?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени друзья. Такой вопрос: как открыть страницу если браузер свернут? к примеру у меня есть всплавающее окно когда браузер свернут и при клике на него что должно происходить? если вопрос не ясен направьте...

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Никто не даст управлять окнами ОС.

Answer (score 0):

я сам нашел)) window.focus();

Comment: И почему я не удивлён, что это не работает?

Answer (score 0):

Ну по идее, если под мелкософт пишите, послать процессу/браузеру команду "максимайз" через скрипты. Но это в теории. Уверен таких скриптов полно, и можно подправить под свои нужды.

[How to detect browser minimize and maximize state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328665/how-to-detect-browser-minimize-and-maximize-state-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
.rootTreeItem.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);

mainWindow.minimize(); //сворачиваем браузер
mainWindow.onTitlebarMaxClick()//разворачиваем браузер
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В каком браузере это работает? В таком виде это не работает даже в IE. И это явно нативные методы, к которым доступ так не дают. Может быть сюда надо присобачить какой-то код на vbscript'е, ограничив применимость браузерами IE10-, но пока оно не работает нигде, насколько я вижу.